# can't load data because namespace 'rlang' 1.06 is already uploaded, but >=1.1.0 is required

Tags: r, rlang

I was able to import my data but now it's saying this whenever I try to import.

I tried downloading rlang, but it keeps doing this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqFVh.jpg)

Comment: try: `install.packages('rlang')` and restart rstudio

Comment: You have to remove the `rlang` first using `remove.packages(rlang)` then install it using `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: @UseR10085 huh? There are _rare_ cases where a package must be removed first, and there's nothing in the screenshot to suggest it. The problem is that it needs to be unloaded (_detached_) from the current process; unfortunately, since `rlang` has compiled libraries (`rlang.dll`), that becomes a little more complicated (esp in windows). Just restarting R and re-installing `rlang` will suffice.

Comment: On my end, what works on Windows is to install Rtools and recompile the rlang package from source. To do that with RStudio, you need to click "yes" when RStudio ask the question after you write install.packages("rlang")